# Transform system to polar and sketch phase portrait. Show that $(0,0)$ is an unstable focus.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, polar-coordinates, fixed-point-theorems, nonlinear-system

> Transform the system
>
> $$x' = y - x(x^2+y^2-1)$$
>
> $$y' = -x - y(x^2+y^2-1)$$
>
> to polar coordinates, and sketch the phase portrait. Show that it has a unique limit cycle and that all trajectories (except the singular point) tend to it as $t \to \infty$. Show therefore that the origin is an **unstable focus**.

---

What I tried:

The system becomes

> $$r' = r(1-r^2)$$
>
> $$\theta' = -1$$

For $0<r<1$, $r'<0 \to (0,0)$ is an **unstable focus**.

For $r>1$, $r'>0 \to (0,0)$ is a **stable focus**.

So I'm guessing we have to show that $r>1$ is problematic? How is it problematic?

Comment: It depends on what do you mean by "problematic". Well, I'll try to not ask this question as far as it possible. To get from $0 < r < 1$ to $r > 1$ a trajectory has to cross $r = 1$. Is there something that prevents trajectories from $0 < r < 1$ or $ r > 1$ to cross $r = 1 $ ?

Comment: @Evgeny I tried analysing both the Cartesian and the polar system when r=1. They seem to have different solutions. R'=0 but x'=y and y'=-x. The former gives $x^2+y^2=C^2$ but the latter gives, well, not that? So the two systems don't agree on $r=1$. What I was thinking for problematic is to show that $r>1$ leads to a contradiction.

Comment: @Evgeny Oh wait you're suggesting to try sketching the trajectories for r>1 and the phase portraits for r<1 and then we're supposed to see that it's problematic to cross from r<1 to r>1?

Comment: No, $r > 1$ doesn't lead to contradiction -- everything is great with system of ODEs when $r > 1$, solutions for sure do exist. You are not correct when you try to decide what kind of stability equilibrium has by looking at points far from its small neighbourhood. However, you already have two kinds of trajectories: ones that go to equilibrium and ones that go away from it. There must be something that separates these families of solutions. Check your solution in cartesian coordinates carefully: it's not $x^2+y^2 = C$ for _many_ values of $C$, it's the *only one* value of $C$.